# How manage Divisions in browser resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm having this HTML/CSS code:

```css
.container
{
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.divisions
{
  border: 1px solid Black;
}

.Fisrt-Line
{
  height: 180px;

}
.First
{
  background-color: Green;
  width: 32.2%;
}
.Second
{
  width: 65%;
  background-color: White;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.Second-Line
{
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: Blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}

.Third-Line
{
  height: 180px;
  width: 31.6%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.Third-2
{
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: Red;
}
.Third-3
{
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <div class=" divisions Fisrt-Line First">
      1</div>
    <div class=" divisions Fisrt-Line Second">
      2</div>
    <div class="divisions Second-Line">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="divisions Third-Line">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="divisions Third-Line Third-2">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="divisions Third-Line Third-3">
      6
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I minimize the browser the second div and also the last div jump to next line. but I don't want that.

How should I edit the code so that those divisions just become smaller not jump to next line?

Comment: Do you want them all horizontally or vertically aligned?

Comment: This is because of using `px` absolute length along percentage. If you want the floated `div` elements stay in-line you should go with percentage for margins as well.

Comment: @HashemQolami i use percentage for margins, it become better but it still has problem...

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari , 2 dives in a line, then 1 div, and in last Line , 3 divs

Comment: @Mahsaehsani Please provide an online demo on jsbin.com/jsfiddle.net/... to demonstrate the issue in action.

Comment: @Mahsaehsani, you need to write media queries where define different style rules for different media screen size, you can read more here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mind to add additional wrappers for rows? if not please take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/ch0L9fy8/2/

Main update here beside row wrappers:

```
.divisions-line {
  width: 100%;
}
.divisions {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid Black;
}
```

Comment: i use css2.1 and it dose not support boxsizing